# Why i can not receive string from USART using this code?

Tags: arduino

After using this code i am not getting anything on serial monitor while it should give me the string which i am sending .am i right that strings which i am sending from serial monitor are null terminated in arduino (and that's why i am waiting for null character in order to get the string) ? Please help

```
    void setup()
    {


      UBRR0 = 103; // for configuring baud rate of 9600bps
      UCSR0C |= (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
      // Use 8-bit character sizes
      UCSR0B |= (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);
      //// Turn on the transmission, reception, and Receive interrupt
      sei();// enable global interrupt

    }


        ISR(USART_RX_vect)
        {
          while (1)
          {

            while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)));
            if (UDR0 != '\0')
            {
              buf[i] = UDR0;
              i++;
            }
            else
            {

              break;
            }
          }
          temp=String(buf);


          uart_send_string(temp); //this function is working properly
        }
```

Comment: Look at the bottom of the serial monitor.  There's a drop down where you can select the line ending.  That's where you can tell it to put a \n at the end.

Comment: Why are you converting your buffer to a String before you send it?  I bet the uart_send_sting function has to convert it back to a char array.  So what's the point of wasting the resources on the String class to convert it just to send it somewhere and convert it back?

Comment: You should NEVER have a while(1) infinite loop in an interrupt handler.  That disables all your other interrupts.  That's not ever a good idea.  Let the interrupt get called each time a character comes in.  Or use the Serial class, it was written by people who know what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't receive a null '\0' character usually.

Unless the sender explicitly sends one. But this is unusual for non-binary data transmission via Serial. The SerialMonitor definitely doesn't!

If you need to notice the end of a message, a newline ( LF , '\n' or 0x0A )  is very common. But any other character might do as well.

---

BTW: As you tag the question `Arduino`, why don't you use the Arduino library for Serial UART communication?